# array split using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have some value stored in array and i wana split them and wana know length of its contains value but when i am running function it is not working

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){


    var valData= ['songs','video','movie','games','other'];

    var valNew=valData.split(',');

    for(i=0;i<valNew.length;i++);

    alert(valNew.length)

    })


</script>


</head>

<body>

<select id="me"></select>
</body>
```

Comment: You are not using a bit of jQuery in this code.

Comment: @bažmegakapa he is using the shorthand for $(document).ready(), although it is not relevant to the question

Comment: @kmb385 Yeah, that's true, but even that is not needed, there is no DOM access in the code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Split is used to separate a delimited string into an array based upon some delimiter passed into the split function.  Your values are already split into an array.  Also your for loop syntax is incorrect.

Split Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Corrected code:

```
$(function(){
    var valData= "songs,video,movie,games,other";

    var valNew=valData.split(',');

    for(var i=0;i<valNew.length;i++){
        alert(valNew.length)
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tmHea/

Comment: +1 But if you are advocating array iteration best practices, it would be nice to cache the `length` AND declare `i` as local (it is GLOBAL now).

Comment: @bažmegakapa good catch, I didn't see that i was global, I have updated.  I agree caching the length would be a good idea but I think the alert will help the original poster realize the code is working.

Comment: How? It would alert the same value all the time.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to split anything, it's already an array. And your for loop syntax is wrong...

```
for (var i = 0; i < valData.length; i++) {

    alert(valData[i].length);

}
```

Comment: Bruv also if you notice lol code is using array of string in `valData` that needs to be corrected as well because without it `split` won't work :) just mentioning bruv, have a good one, cheerios!

Comment: `for (var i = 0, len = valData.length; i < len; i++)` to cache the `length` and make a really "right" iteration.

Answer (score 3):

Hiya **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/YCarA/8/

2 things are wrong

1) for loop.

2) your `valData` is array it should be string for split to format as array.

**jquery code**

```
$(function(){


    var valData = "songs,video,movie,games,other";


    var valNew = valData.split(',');

    for(var i=0;i<valNew.length;i++){

      alert(valNew.length);

   }
    });​
```

Comment: Please make that `i` local (and cache the `length`).

Comment: @bažmegakapa sure bruv gimme 1 minute please I used the code from above, 1 min :) thanks! and done now! +1

Answer (score 1):

Kmb385 is right. Your data is you can not split to array it is already separated.

Also your for loop is faulty the correct one is

```
for(var i=0;i<valNew.length;i++)
      alert(valNew[i].length);
```

Comment: Please make that `i` local (and cache the `length`) - if talking about faulty/correct loops.

Answer (score 1):

The [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) way :

```
var valData = ["songs","video","movie","games","other"];
$.each(valData, function(key, value) {
   alert("Index ---> " + key + ' & length of item ---> ' + value.length);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XJxdj/1/)