# how to split values of array using jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to split the data in the array , the sample data is as the following .

```
 var data = [1, "Asia,11,3,0,27.0,0.0"];
```

How to split this into two values

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Does this answer your question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257605/array-split-using-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you mean this:

```
var data = [1, "Asia,11,3,0,27.0,0.0"];
var first = data[0]; // 1
var second = data[1]; // "Asia,11,3,0,27.0,0.0"
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution is apt for my requirement

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy with Array methods. For example, you can expand your array like this:

```
data.splice.apply(data, [1, 1].concat(data[1].split(',')));
```

And there is a demo:

```js
var data = [1, "Asia,11,3,0,27.0,0.0"];

data.splice.apply(data, [1, 1].concat(data[1].split(',')));

// print result
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify( data, null, 4 ) + '</pre>');
```

Check useful [Array.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) methods:

- [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
- [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

and [String.prototype.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method.